# Do Nuclear Power Plants have shutdown and cooling systems protected from a nuclear generated EMP?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Forty years ago, I read a report concerning the difficulties of protecting my companies equipment, which was to be installed in Air Force One, from a Nuclear EMP. An EMP generated by a high altitude nuclear detonation seemed particularly problematic. It raises concern about our power plants ability to safely shutdown and cool a core after a nuclear generated EMP. Adding to the concern is the fact that all civilian equipment would be inoperative and unable to assist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear plants are designed with a high degree of [passive safety measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_nuclear_safety), which come in far too many varieties to list here. Basically, the idea is that your systems need to be working correctly in order to maintain power generation. Normal operation involves actively suppressing physical processes that themselves suppress nuclear reactions. When something goes wrong, the reaction quenches itself.

For example, your fuel may be regulated by a neutron absorber whose cross section increases with increasing temperature, thus providing a negative feedback loop on the fuel temperature that necessitates no human intervention nor electronic equipment.

You should also note that the public perception of nuclear plants is **way** off-base when it comes to their risks. I've encountered many people in the US who legitimately believe that if you look at them the wrong way, most nuclear power plants will overheat and melt through to the core of the Earth (thanks to certain B-list science fiction films); they also believe Three Mile Island and Fukushima killed hundreds of people each. The fact is, the worst thing you can reasonably expect to happen to a nuclear plant not run by the disintegrating remains of the Soviet Union is that it will shut itself off and therefore fail to provide power. Besides, if there were a nuclear explosion close enough and powerful enough to fry all of your electronics, you have **far bigger problems** than an overheated nuclear plant.

Comment: While I agree that the public perception of the risks of nuclear power are exaggerated it doesn't help to dismiss the actual risks. The failures at Three Mile Island and Fukushima resulted in billions of dollars of damage to the infrastructure of those plants and in the case of Fukushima did result in significant radioactive contamination of the surrounding area. That's a far cry from 'the worst thing you can expect is failure to provide power'.

Comment: The local news here did describe the 2nd anniversary of the earthquake and NUCLEAR DISASTER in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

An ElectroMagnetic Pulse (EMP) is generated high in the atmosphere as a hostile act in war, a nuclear detonation generating electromagnetic pulses [at three levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse), by the 1 MeV gammas of the detonation and their secondary effects, and by displacing the magnetic field of the earth and generating a pulse similar to the solar electromagnetic pulses.

Reactors are built with heavy shields so as to ensure that no radiation from the core escapes to the environment. This means they are also shielded for high energy gammas and secondary xray energies  coming from above. In a war situation they should certainly be shielded with an appropriate metal shield for lower frequency electromagnetic pulses.

The only danger could come through surges in incoming power lines, from the area power grid, and if they are  properly protected from surges there should be no problem of loss of control.

Answer (score 0):

US nuclear power plants are basically designed to want to shut down.
Operators have to constantly work every hour of every day to monitor systems in order to keep it going. If anything that's system critical has an issue then the system will automatically trip a shut down of the reactor.

After that the only task involved to keep things safe is really just to keep the reactor cool. And there are multiple redundancies of back up pumps and coolant supplies to guarantee this happens. The plant I work at has a massive lake next to it to pull water from as well as a nearby river that feeds the lake. And there's multiple diesel generators to power pumps to bring that water into the plant.

With that said the reactor itself is in a containment building which has about 4 feet or more thick walls of concrete and steel. An EMP may wreck havoc on things outside but everything inside will be fine.

The NRC put out a report on EMP's in 1983 stating as much. They also put one out on solar storms in 1989.